# Cardview onclick opens a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Clicking a card opens an activity then clicking on another card opens another activity and so on. Is there any way to create just one activity and recognize id of the card clicked and show its corresponding data ??

Comment: 1.set id's for each card view. 
2.implement View.onClickListener
3.override onClick method
4.compare Id's
5. make intent

Comment: Sure there is. Pass some data with the `Intent.putExtra` ( e.g. cardview's position, id, text in it, whatever)

Comment: thanks for the solution guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send id with `Intent.putExtra` and then get it with `Intent.getIntExtra` in your activity and provide your data in activity

Here is an example that sending id and index to MyActtivity if youre using `ListView`:

```
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",view.getId());
        intent.putExtra("index",position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

And you can retrieve it in MyActivity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
int id = intent.getIntExtra("id",0);
int index = intent.getIntExtra("index",0);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution @Amir_P if u have an example of that please post it thanks again

Comment: I've edited my post. if it helps you accept my answer @Ace

Answer (score -1):

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    }

    public void card(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ActivitymainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop duplicating answers, especially as you have not bothered to write an explanation.